# Reference a variable inside a string with groovy

Tags: string, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Sorry if it was not clear enough.

I have the following groovy snippet (from Jenkins)

```
def jdk = jobConfig.java

jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME="${tool '$jdk'}"
jobConfig.env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

How can I substitute the value of `$jdk` variable inside the single quotes on this line?

```
jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME="${tool '$jdk'}"
```

For example, this works with no problems. The usage of tools is OK:

```
jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'openjdk_11.0.14'}"
```

But I want to set the hardcoded value of 'openjdk_11.0.14' to the value coming from `def jdk = jobConfig.java`

I tried a few variations but couldn't find the solution.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "_How can I reference the $jdk variable inside the single quotes..._"? Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Additional question: are you implying that `$jdk` is a shell environment variable, and not a Groovy/Pipeline scope variable?

Comment: "are you implying that $jdk is a shell environment variable" - That code doesn't imply that. The code is explicit in defining that variable with `def jdk = jobConfig.java`.

Comment: I update the question to make it clearer I hope.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reference the $jdk variable inside the single quotes?

It isn't clear what you mean by that but what you have is this:

```
jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME="${tool '$jdk'}"
```

There are a few things wrong with that but to address how to deal with the single quotes, 1 of the issues is you have nested `$` which is going to confuse the situation.

if you are trying to surround the value of `jdk` with single quotes, you can do this:

```
def someJavaHomeRelatedVariable ="'${jdk}'"
```

Note that the quotes are outside of the `{}` expression.

A separate issue is your use of `tool` in that expression, but the above explains how to deal with surrounding the value of `jdk` with single quotes.

**EDIT**

The question isn't clear but maybe you are wanting to do something like this:

```
def sout = new StringBuilder()
def jdk = jobConfig.java

def proc = ['tool', jdk].execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, null)
proc.waitForOrKill(2000)

jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME =  sout.toString()
```

Comment: If you are trying to execute a command named `tool` and pass the value of `jdk` as a parameter, that is trivial too, but it isn't clear that is what you intend to do.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer I hope.

Comment: `jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'openjdk_11.0.14'}"` - Are you trying to execute `tool 'openjdk_11.0.114'` as a shell command and assign whatever is written to stdout to be the value assigned to `jobConfig.env.JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: I just want to set the jdk for this job to openjdk_11.0.14 which is configured in the Global Tools of jenkins.

This syntax does not work:
```
tools {
  jdk "openjdk_11.0.14"
}
```

It says:
```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'tools' found among steps
```

Comment: Jeff scott brown, can you tell me how to use the tool expression correctly?

Comment: "Jeff scott brown, can you tell me how to use the tool expression correctly?" - Are you trying to execute a shell command called `tool`, pass it a parameter, and capture whatever that tool writes to stdout?